# More elegant way to form n-digit range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, range, dynamically-generated

I need to form a range of numbers depending on input param `n`. If `n=1` range is `range(0, 10)`, if `n=2` then `range(10, 100)`.

I have a code, but it looks ugly, maybe there is better way.

```
start = 0 if n == 1 else int('1' + '0' * (n - 1))
end = 10 if n == 1 else 10 * start
for i in range(start, end):
```

For `n=1` it should be:

```
range(0, 10) 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: how about using `pow`?

Comment: `start = 0 if n == 1 else 10 ** (n - 1)`

Comment: This question might better belong on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In general, you can use a dictionary to simplify these things: `d = {1: (0, 10), 2: (10, 100)}`. Then it's a simple lookup: `for i in range(*d[n]):`. This is easier if your start and endpoints don't have a trivial mathematical relationship to `n` and scales easily.

Comment: How about `for i in range(10**(n-1), 10**n):`?

Comment: @rchang That returns the wrong range for the case `n == 1` (as do many of the answers below).

Comment: @Phylogenesis You're right - I just moments ago realized that corner case.  :)  I think YuriMalheiros has an answer that covers it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if n == 1:
  interval = range(0, 10**n)
else:
  interval = range(10**(n-1), 10**n)
```

If your range for n=1 is range(1,10), you can use just: `range(10**(n-1), 10**n)` without the if clause

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> range(pow(10, n), pow(10, n)*10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


>>> range(pow(10, n), pow(10, n)*10)
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows you, how you can use pow `math.pow`, to solve your usecase.
It does not solve every detail, but it points you in the right direction.

```
>>> from math import pow
>>> n = 1
>>> range(int(pow(10, n - 1)), int(pow(10, n)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> n = 2
>>> range(int(pow(10, n - 1)), int(pow(10, n)))
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

>>> n = -1
>>> range(int(pow(10, n - 1)), int(pow(10, n)))
[]
```

You need to make sure that n is bigger den 0 :-)

EDIT 1:
As viakondratiuk mentioned in if `n` is 1, it should start from 0, not 1.

EDIT 2:

You may use `**` notation to avoid casting the float to int.

```
>>> n = 2
>>> range(10 ** (n - 1), 10 ** n)
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: for n=1 start should be 0

Comment: Why the cast to `int`?  `math.pow` returns an integer for integer arguments.  Also, why do you prefer `math.pow(x, y)` to `x**y`?

Comment: `pow(10, 1)` returns `10.0`

Comment: @Mathias:  You are correct.  I was looking at the Python 2 behavior.  In Python 3 it returns a float.  I guess that's another reason to use `10 ** 1`.  Even stranger, the 2.7.9 docs claim that both numbers are converted to float, but `type(pow(10, 1))` returns `<type 'int'>` on my computer.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: You might be running the code with Python 2.x.

Comment: I'm not aware of which python version returns int?? Python 3.3.2 `type(pow(10, 1))` --> `<class 'float'>`. And Python 2.7.5 also float. But the `**` notation returns an `int` on both versions, so I agree this ist the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pow` in combination with `range` (in Python 2.7, use `xrange`, which saves you from allocating the whole list in memory):

```
n = 1
start = pow(10, n)
r = (range(10) if n == 1 else range(start, start * 10))
[i for i in r]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: for n=1 start should be 0

Comment: Yes, I'm using python3, changed tags.